# HM10/11 BLE to Android Phone connectivity

Tags: android, android-studio, arduino, hm-10

First off I would like to ask if it is possibe to send a stream of data from an arduino with HM11 to an android phone via bluetooth.

The data contains ultrasonic sensor's readings, orientation, battery level, etc.

My android phone will be displaying those data accordingly acting as a monitor.

I tried coding already using the android studio using the bluetooth guide resources but i end up unable to connect to my module with a message "read failed, closed or timeout -1". I have tried connecting while paired or unpaired. My app can discover HM11 as well as receive the data using HMBLE Terminal app i have downloaded from Play Store. So I guess the android studio guides are not meant from android to bluetooth modules.

I would also like to begin from scratch as i may have missed out some very important basic information.

Any help?

Comment: yes it should be possible, after discovering and paring bluetooth, your computer would create a com port, then you will need to connect to the new com port, if you need a code to fetch data via com port let me know

Comment: Sorry i got confused with the com port. Im trying to send data from arduino to my phone via bluetooth not to a PC

Comment: I got you sorry, i have not tried it with phone, but theoretically it should be possible practically have not try it before